# Count elements in an array over a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a two arrays, `[a,b]` and `[c,d,e,f,g,h]`. Possible values within the arrays are 0, 1, 2 and 3.

A variable is set based on the values in these arrays meeting certain conditions:

- n = 3: *everything* in the first array =3, *at least* 2 values in the second array =3, *no values* in either array =0
- n = 2: *everything* in the first array >=2, *at least* 4 values in the second array >=2, *no values* in either array =0
- n = 1: *everything* in the first array >=1, *at least* 4 values in the second array >=1
- n = 0: anything else

Is there a less verbose way of writing this than having a large number of count `for` loops that all run with a slightly different condition?

Comment: You could sort the arrays, then find the last index of the value that meets your conditions.

Comment: do you have some real examples?

Comment: Show what you have and we'd be happy to improve on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following without a lot of for loop,

```
let a = [2,2,2,2];
let b = [2,2,2,2,3,1];

let countA = {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0};
let countB = {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0};

a.forEach(item => {
  countA[item]++;
}) 

b.forEach(item => {
  countB[item]++;
}) 

let n = 0;
if(countA[3] === a.length && countB[3] >= 2 && countB[0] === 0 && countA[0] === 0) {
  n = 3;
} else if(countA[3] + countA[2] === a.length && countB[2] + countB[3] >= 4 && countB[0] === 0 && countA[0] === 0) {
  n = 2;
} else if(countA[1] + countA[2] + countA[3] === a.length && countB[1] + countB[2] + countB[3] >= 4 && countB[0] === 0 && countA[0] === 0) {
  n = 1;
}

console.log(n);
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you, I totally overlooked the option of just adding the counts given the limited range of values.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage array methods `Array#every()` and `Array#filter()` as follows:

```js
let a = [2,3];
let b = [2,2,2,2,3,0];
let c = [1,0];
let d = [2,3,0,0,1,1];
let e = [3,3];
let f = [3,3,3,2,2,2];

console.log( von(a,b) );
console.log( von(c,d) );
console.log( von(e,f) );


function von(a, b) {
    return [3,2,1,0]
    .filter(
        v => a.every(x => x>=v) && 
        b.filter(y => y>=v).length >= (v===3?2:4) &&
        b.filter(y => y===0).length <= ([3,2].includes(v)?0:3)
    )
    [0];
}
```